# Is there a way to get individual items in a sortable connected list with jquery ui after item was removed from list?

Tags: jquery-ui

I Have the following problem: After an item was being dragged out from the "sortable_pics_selected" list into the other list there is an event being fired with jquery ui "remove" event handler:

-->fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4DBLj/3/ <---

```
 $("#sortable_pics_selected").sortable({
            remove: function(event, ui) {
                alert('hi);
            }
        });


<div id="sortablecontainer_pic"> 
   <ul id="sortable_pics_all" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
   </ul>

   <ul id="sortable_pics_selected" class="connectedSortable">
      <li id="1" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
      <li id="2" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
      <li id="3" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
      <li id="4" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
      <li id="5" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a way to figure out which id the removed item has? The above function just fires in general when any item was removed...what might be the best way to get the individual id? Is there a jquery ui function that can do this? If this is not the case...the remove method seems to me not being the right thing. I could write it in pure jquery but for this things jquery ui was build? Did i misunderstand something?

Comment: syntax error in `alert('hi); `

Comment: thats a good one! but thats not the problem..;-P

Comment: given the limited code above, I don't see how the "remove" will ever fire. Am I missing something? (taking the syntax error out of consideration of course :)

Comment: hi...hmm try to get this fiddle working but until now no success:  
http://jsfiddle.net/4DBLj/3/

Comment: Your fiddle is using mootools not jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your Fiddle, here is the final code

http://jsfiddle.net/4DBLj/5/

Get the id attribute of the ui item:

```
alert(ui.item.attr('id'));
```

EDIT: Regarding the ui.item comment "where i can read about the ui.class".

jQuery UI has documentation on each of the widgets.  While many include "ui" the actual content of that may vary.  For the Sortable see this page:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/
  Under the "Overview" tab.  There you will find a reference to ui.item - the current dragged item.  Which, in this instance has an attribute of "id" because you included one in your code "id=''" for that object.

Comment: Incidently, `$(this)` will refer to the list of things left as a jquery object :)

Comment: yeah i did this before ;-P Do you konwo where i can read about the ui.class? I found nothing substantial on the official ui site...by the way...cool surname...nice Berlin beer http://www.schultheiss.de/ !! Greetings from Germany!

Comment: haha :-) Greetings from India. By the way, frankly what I did was, do console.log(ui) and then opened the Chrome console to study that object.

Comment: @NikhilBaliga - I appreciate your edit to my answer HOWEVER, you should NOT remove code from an answer and ONLY provide a fiddle alone.  It is considered better form I believe to provide code and if needed an example however, the answer still should stand alone without visiting the referenced page.

Comment: See some comments here regarding this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer  and this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following? I believe it should work

```
    ui.attr('id')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer...its says: its not a function...but that would be awesome though!

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a Fiddle?

Comment: You can see my changes here http://jsfiddle.net/4DBLj/5/
Your dragging was not working because you had not enabled jQuery andjQuery UI on the left